# Swing layout with resizable and fixed-size labels

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have `JPanel` with 2 `JLabels` which need to be placed int a row one after another:

[image: First View]

But when the first `JLabel` contains very long text I want it to be truncated, but show whole second `JLabel`, like following:

[image]

I've tried `BorderLayout` for this but it makes *Second Label Text* be always aligned to the right of the `JPanel` which is not exactly what I need.

Could you please advise the proper way to achive the desired layout?

Comment: Truncate the text of the first label in your code.

Comment: Text should be truncated automatically. It should be responsibility of LayoutManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a horizontal `BoxLayout`.

The key is to make the minimum size of the first component (0, 0);

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();

JLabel longLabel = new JLabel("this has lots fo text");
longLabel.setMinimumSize( new Dimension(0, 0) );
box.add(longLabel);

box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));

JLabel shortLabel = new JLabel("little text");
box.add(shortLabel);
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I need! Thanks a lot for help.